# set references in the XML file to XSLT and XSD files which are packed into archive

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Is it possible to set references in the XML file to XSLT and XSD files which are packed into some archive? If so, how can you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, there is no generic, platform independent, interoperable way to set this up.

Each framework (Java, .NET, etc.) would have its own out of box approaches (or not), which is typically linked with:

- supported [URI schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)
- how XML parsers resolve external references;
- support for external [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605767/produce-xml-files-that-inherit-from-other-xml-files).

It also depends a lot on how you expect these references to work for you, how you want the references to look like, which drives how those can be resolved at parsing time.

If you want everything done by the XML parser, you may want to look at XInclude and alike, using a URI scheme supported for your archive; if there is one, e.g. in Java you could try jar://, then this is your solution.

If your scheme is not supported but your platform allows to define new handlers, or override existing ones, for URI schemes, then it might be solved simply with your custome handler.

Another alternative is to build you own helper "service" that augments the standard parsing, and while at it, it scans the XML for your specific external reference nodes, and it replaces those reference nodes with content pulled from your external references, coming from your archive.

The only other serious problem I see is when your XSLT and XSD are authored across multiple files.

Comment: it is necessary for me, that it worked in the browser, without necessity of installation of additional platforms and libraries.

Comment: @Bush, I believe browsers are pretty limited to what they would be able to reference, say in an xml-stylesheet processing instruction; if the XSD is to be referenced for validation purposes, through schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation, then browsers typically don't process these attributes. XML content is generally opaque to browsers, except for processing instructions, or when the mime type is something for which they have a plugin defined. It is still not clear to me exactly how the interaction would be between these: browser, XML, external references...